# Помогите разобрать JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий фрагмент кода, что он значит?

```
    jQuery(".part").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle(jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".part").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle(jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
});
```

Давайте немного преобразуем код для ясности:

```
jQuery(".part").filter(function() {
  var $element = $(this); // Один из елементов .part
  var innerText = jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase(); // Текст елемента в нижнем регистре
  var textContainsWord = innerText.indexOf(value) > -1; // Если текст содержит value (значение переменной не упомянуто в коде), будет true, иначе - false
  $element.toggle(textContainsWord); // вызывает метод $element.toggle(true) или $element.toggle(false)
});
```

Функция `filter` в даном случае просто проходится по елементам, так что ее можно заменить на `each`.

---

Данный код проходится по елементам с классом "part" и вызывает к ним метод toggle с параметром, зависящим от текста елемента.

Comment: Да, спасибо) Я уже конечно сам разобрался, но в любом случае, спасибо.